# More customizable flash mp3 player for website?

Tags: audio, mp3

the only mp3 flash player I've see has been the Google Audio widget which is limited in its appearance.

http://www.widgetbox.com/widget/mp3

For my wordpress, I like the player I use 1 Pixel Out's, which is great:

http://www.1pixelout.net/code/audio-player-wordpress-plugin/

Anyway I could use this without much coding on a regular, non-wordpress, php page?

Comment: Not quite. superuser is for user related questions. She is asking a question with the intention to do some 'coding' therefore it belongs here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the standalone version of pixelone.

Answer (score 1):

In a three step process you could add it to any webpage you like; in my book that is not too much coding at all. It's actually rather nice. The tutorial for how to do that can be found here: http://www.macloo.com/examples/audio_player/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend A2 mp3 player - http://flashstall.com/7. It has a standalone version that can be used in general html/php pages and a wordpress plugin version that can be used in WP blogs.